# material-table space between rows

Tags: css, reactjs, material-table

I am using [material-table](https://material-table.com/#/)
and I want to add space between rows to make such look:
[table design](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1BR8A.jpg)

I tried to set padding in rowStyle in options like this:

```
      <MaterialTable
        title=""
        columns={state.columns}
        data={state.data}
        options={{
          pageSize: 15,
          pageSizeOptions: [10, 15, 25, 50],
          searchFieldAlignment: 'left',
          rowStyle: {
            paddingBottom: '5px'
          }
        }}
      />
```

Answer (score 0):

you can achieve it via:

```
rowStyle: {
            borderBottom: '5px solid white',
          }
```

Comment: it changed the border color but there is no space between the rows

Comment: Doesn’t that give you the same Visual result as if there was some spacing? Padding/margin didn’t work as options for MaterialTable for me

Comment: as you can see on the attached pic, the border color should be changed dynamically, so in this case I need to find a way to set space between rows

Comment: **borderBottom: `${widthVariableValue} solid ${colorVariable}`,** you can use these variables to pass variables and it should work for you